# sql statement to change somehow related rows

Tags: mysql, sql

The problem: I have a MySQL database table which holds article numbers and 2 parameters related to the article:

```
article_no | parameter1 | parameter2

1111111    | false      | false

2111111    | true       | true

1222222    | false      | false

2222222    | false      | false
```

Articles are represented by 2 article numbers, the difference is that one starts with "1", the other starts with "2".

The problem: parameter2 of all article numbers starting with "1" has to become "true" if parameter1 of the related "2"-article number is true. in the example above parameter2 of 1111111 has to become "true". is there way to do this with sql only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with one `UPDATE` query, like:

```
UPDATE 
  t AS l 
    LEFT JOIN t AS r 
      ON SUBSTR(l.article_no, 2)=SUBSTR(r.article_no, 2) 
      AND l.article_no LIKE '1%' 
      AND r.article_no LIKE '2%' 
SET 
  l.parameter2='true' 
WHERE 
  r.parameter1='true'
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you want to update the parameter 1 and 2 with following condition:if prefix is '1' then 'true' and if the prefix is '2' then false. Here's the query:

```
UPDATE article SET parameter1 = 'true', parameter2 = 'true' WHERE article_no LIKE '1%';

UPDATE article SET parameter1 = 'false', parameter2 = 'false' WHERE article_no LIKE '2%';
```

I assume that your table would be `article`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer

```
update 
    articles as a 
left join 
    articles as b
on 
    substring(a.article_no, 2) = substring(b.article_no, 2)
set 
    a.parameter2 = 'true'
where 
    a.artile_no like '1%' 
    and b.artile_no like '2%'
    and b.parameter2 = 'true';
```

By the way you have presented the problem parameter2 for the rows which have an article number that starts with '1' has to become true **only if** parameter2 is true for the corresponding row which has a article_no starting with '2'. If you don't care about the value of parameter2 for the rows with article number starting with '2' just remove the last condition.

The main idea is that you have to make your comparison using the substring() function and parameter 2.

```
 substring(a.article_no, 2) = substring(b.article_no,2)
```

The same operation can be done using subqueries but using left join is more cost effective.